# Type hints and chained assignment and multiple assignments

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, chained-assignment

I guess these two questions are related, so I'll post them together:

**1.- Is it possible to put type hint in chained assignments?**

These two attempts failed:

```
>>> def foo(a:int):
...     b: int = c:int = a
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    b: int = c:int = a
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> def foo(a:int):
...     b = c:int = a
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    b = c:int = a
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**2.- Is it possible to put type hint in multiple assignments?**

These were my attempts:

```
>>> from typing import Tuple
>>> def bar(a: Tuple[int]):
...     b: int, c:int = a
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    b: int, c:int = a
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> def bar(a: Tuple[int]):
...     b, c:Tuple[int] = a
... 
  File "<stdin>", line 2
SyntaxError: only single target (not tuple) can be annotated
>>> def bar(a: Tuple[int]):
...     b, c:int = a
... 
  File "<stdin>", line 2
SyntaxError: only single target (not tuple) can be annotated
```

I am aware that in both cases the type is inferred from the type hint of a, but I have a long variable list (in the `__init__` of a class) and I want to be extra-explicit.

I am using Python 3.6.8.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

1. As explicitly stated in [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/), section "Rejected/postponed proposals", annotations in chained assignments are not supported.  Quoting the PEP:

   > This has problems of ambiguity and readability similar to tuple unpacking, for example in:
   >   `x: int = y = 1`
   >   `z = w: int = 1`
   >   it is ambiguous, what should the types of y and z be? Also the second line is difficult to parse.
2. For unpacking, per the same PEP, you should place bare annotations for your variables before the assignment. Example from the PEP:

   ```
   # Tuple unpacking with variable annotation syntax
   header: str
   kind: int
   body: Optional[List[str]]
   header, kind, body = message
   ```

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. However, it is already four years from the question and answer. Have things changed or is the answer still the (only) correct way? Intuitively I would write, for example, `a: int, b: str = func()` for a function returning `tuple[int, str]`. But it does not work.