# How to do type hint when multiple return value assigned to different variable in python3

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, return-type, python-typing

In my code I create a function foo which returns two values which I assign to two different variable but I could not define types for those two variables

```
def foo(a: int, b:int) -> Tuple[int, int]:
  return a+5, b+5
```

Now When I tried to call the function I am unable to assign types to those variable.
I want something like this

```
a: int, b: int = foo(5, 10)
```

But it is not working. I am `getting syntax error`
[Error after compiling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crYmZ.png)

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/56611983/3001761

Answer (score 0):

here is correct function

```
def foo(a: int, b: int) -> tuple[int, int]:
    return a+5, b+5
```

and you can't use `a: int` in creating 2 or more variables using `,`. just write:

```
a, b = foo(5, 10)
```

Comment: OP's function is correct too, support to use generics on types like `tuple` without using `typing.Tuple` was quite recent.